# How to hide address bar while opening the window?

Tags: asp.net

I am writing like this to hide addressbar.It contain scrollbar, but I not able to maximize the window

```
window.open("sample.aspx?id="+id+"","win32","toolbar=no,resize=yes,scrollbars=yes,maximize=yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.0 and higher have disabled setting `location` by default. `resizable` and `status` are also disabled by default. You can verify this by typing `about:config' in your address bar and filtering by "dom". The items of interest are:

- dom.disable_window_open_feature.location
- dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable
- dom.disable_window_open_feature.status

You can get further information at the [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) site. What this basically means, though, is that you won't be able to do what you want to do.

One thing you might want to do (though it won't solve your problem), is put quotes around your window feature parameters, like so:

```
window.open('/pageaddress.html','winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
```